# Mapping Nested Checkbox not working ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a function which triggers children checkboxes once main checkbox is checked, and all these checkboxes are mapped from JSON. The main checkboxes (Highest order) and all of its children checkboxes (2nd order) under them are shown on check and its working great, what i am trying to show is the children of those children of the main checkboxes (3rd order).

Basically to show all three orders under each other on check, and add the 3rd order to my current code, so **Options Group** shows **Options**, and under **Options** is what i want to show, which are **Option 1**, **Option 2**, **option 3** and so on..

The checkbox values are passed as props from **Checkbox.js** to **Itemlist.js** where the fetch/map happens.

As I was trying to achieve this, I have been able to show each of these 3rd order checkboxes but each one alone instead of showing them as nested checkboxes. I've tried to include it in the existing mapping function to show them all as nested checkboxes as mentioned but it couldn't work it only works if it was mapped alone instead of the current mapped path which is const *selectedItem*. while the mapping path of the targeted checkboxes (3rd level) are added in **Itemlist.js** as const *selectedMod*,

Main Snippet : https://codesandbox.io/embed/6jykwp3x6n?fontsize=14

What I reached for so far to show the targeted checkboxes but individually: https://codesandbox.io/embed/o932z4yr6y?fontsize=14

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Checkbox.css";

class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentData: 0,
      limit: 2,
      checked: false
    };
  }

  selectData(id, event) {
    let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
    if (isSelected) {
      if (this.state.currentData < this.props.max) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData + 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (this.state.currentData >= this.props.min) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData - 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = true;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const input2Checkboxes =
      this.props.options &&
      this.props.options.map(item => {
        return (
          <div className="inputGroup2">
            {" "}
            <div className="inputGroup">
              <input
                id={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
                name="checkbox"
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={this.selectData.bind(
                  this,
                  this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)
                )}
              />
              <label
                htmlFor={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
              >
                {item.name || item.description}{" "}

              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });

    return (
      <form className="form">
        <div>
          {/** <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>*/}
          <div className="inputGroup">
            <input
              id={this.props.childk + this.props.name}
              name="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.checked}
              onChange={this.selectData.bind(
                this,
                this.props.childk + this.props.uniq
              )}
              onChange={() => {
                this.setState({
                  checked: !this.state.checked,
                  currentData: 0
                });
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor={this.props.childk + this.props.name}>
              {this.props.name}{" "}
            </label>
          </div>{" "}
          {this.state.checked ? input2Checkboxes : undefined}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

**Itemlist.js** Where the mapping function happen

```
...

      const selectedItem =
        selectedChild.children && selectedChild.children.length
          ? selectedChild.children[this.state.itemSelected]
          : null;

...

  <div>
                {selectedItem &&
                  selectedItem.children &&
                  selectedItem.children.map((item, index) => (
                    <Checkboxes
                      key={index}
                      name={item.name || item.description}
                      myKey={index}
                      options={item.children}
                      childk={item.id}
                      max={item.max}
                      min={item.min}
                    />
                  ))}
              </div>
...
```